# JCodeModel in maven project

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven, maven-plugin, maven-3

I am new to use JCodeModel. could anyone provide me a simple demo or link how to use JCodeModel in maven project? Where do I need to exatly place the JCodeModel class in maven to generate java class?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using two different maven plugins to achieve this. First I used the maven ant plugin to compile my codemodel code. Then I used the exec plugin to run the codemodel code, so that the maven build can build the generated classes as part of the build. I have put the maven bits below:

```
       <plugins>
          ...
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>sun.jdk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
                    <version>1.5.0</version>
                    <scope>system</scope>
                    <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>1</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <mkdir dir="${basedir}/target/classes" />
                            <javac srcdir="${basedir}/src/main/java/com/generation/" destdir="${basedir}/target/classes" classpathref="maven.compile.classpath">
                            </javac>
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>2</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <executable>java</executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>-classpath</argument>
                    <!-- automatically creates the classpath using all project dependencies,
                    also adding the project build directory -->
                    <classpath/>
                    <argument>com.generation.CodeGeneration</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
        </plugins>
```